# Qual a diferença entre "ter que" e "ter de"?

Tags: gramática

Escuto pessoas usando as duas formas mas não consigo entender a diferença, se tiver uma. Pesquisei um pouco no Google e fiquei entendendo que "ter de" é para obrigação e "ter que" para probabilidade, mas isso não concorda com o uso diário que encontro.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "probabilidade"? Teria algum exemplo de frase com esse sentido? Não me recordo de já ter visto essa expressão sendo usada dessa forma.

Comment: Já pesquisei acerca disto no passado e na minha opinião e de acordo com [este](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/duvidas-sobre-o-ter-de-e-o-ter-que/14247) link, as respostas abaixo não estão completamente corretas.

Comment: @GitGud poderá elaborar a sua opinião?

Comment: @Armfoot De acordo com o link acima, "ter que" nada tem a ver com probabilidade. Das várias vezes que li acerca disto, esta é a primeira em que vejo falar de probabilidade.

Comment: @GitGud quando se fala numa [possibilidade de algo acontecer](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/possibilidade), existe uma [probabilidade (deriva do Latim _probare_ = provar ou testar)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilidade) associada ao acontecimento: "tem que fazer" ou "tem que experimentar" sugere implicitamente a probabilidade de algo acontecer. Daí a interpretação do Jorge: o Sandy, autor da pergunta, [acabou por confirmar em baixo](http://alturl.com/w56np) que se referia à possibilidade inerente a "ter que experimentar". Nessa página do ciberduvidas, este caso não foi considerado.

Comment: No Brazil essa expressão "ter de" quase nunca é usada. A expressão "ter que" indica obrigatoriedade e necessidade também.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### **[English]**

> The grammatical tradition have insisted in **ter de** as the correct expression to refer to **necessity or obligation**.
>
> However, the form **ter que** starts being registered even by lexicographers as **synonym** of **ter de** [...],  I have to admit that the use of **ter que** is practically legitimated.
>
> «que fazer», «que contar», «que estudar», «que comer», «que dizer» assume, [...] as if they could be replaced by «trabalho» or «afazeres», «relatos», «estudo», «comida», «palavras», etc.: «ele **tem que fazer**» = ele **tem trabalho**, tem afazeres; «ele **tem que comer**» = ele **tem comida**; «ele **não tem que dizer**» = ele **não tem palavras**.
>
> And between the verb «ter» and the relative pronoun «que» may be added an undefined one (tanto, muito, pouco).

The expression **ter que** may be related to *probability* if we see it with a suggestion perspective of a possibility. E.g.:

> [Jorge B.](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/153/jorge-b) said that *você/tu **tem/tens que** experimentar sushi*.

So Jorge suggest that there's a possibility and probability for you to eat sushi and like it, however in the end you may or may not follow this suggestion (without obligatoriness of accomplishment).

However, the idea of **obligation** is present in **ter de**, as refereed:

> **Ter de distinguish from ter que**, because in the **first case** is present the idea of **obligation**, of necessity, of duty, while in the **second** is present the idea of to give an **information about what the speaker have** or hold on hands.

You can read more at [ciberduvidas, «Ter que» vs. «ter de»](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/ter-que-vs-ter-de/16291) and at [Dúvidas sobre o «ter de» e o «ter que»](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/duvidas-sobre-o-ter-de-e-o-ter-que/14247) .

---

### **[Português]**

> A tradição gramatical tem insistido em **ter de** como a expressão correta para referir a **necessidade ou a obrigação**.
>
> Contudo, a forma **ter que** começa a ser registada até por lexicógrafos como **sinónima** de **ter de** [...],  tenho de reconhecer que o uso de **ter que** está praticamente legitimado.
>
> «que fazer», «que contar», «que estudar», «que comer», «que dizer» assumem, [...] como se pudessem ser substituídos por «trabalho» ou «afazeres», «relatos», «estudo», «comida», «palavras», etc.: «ele **tem que fazer**» = ele **tem trabalho**, tem afazeres; «ele **tem que comer**» = ele **tem comida**; «ele **não tem que dizer**» = ele **não tem palavras**.
>
> E entre o verbo «ter» e o pronome relativo «que» poderá ser colocado um indefinido (tanto, muito, pouco).

A expressão **ter que** poderá estar relacionada com *probabilidade* se a virmos numa perspetiva de sugestão de uma possibilidade. E.g.:

> O [Jorge B.](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/153/jorge-b) disse que *você/tu **tem/tens que** experimentar sushi*.

O Jorge sugere então que existe uma possibilidade e probabilidade de você comer sushi e gostar, porém no final pode ou não seguir essa sugestão (sem obrigatoriedade de concretização).

No entanto, a ideia de **obrigação** está presente em **ter de**, como referiu:

> **Ter de distingue-se**, pois, **de ter que**, porque no **primeiro caso** está presente a ideia da **obrigação**, da necessidade, do dever, enquanto no **segundo** está presente a de dar uma **informação sobre o que o emissor possui** ou tem em mãos.

Pode ler mais em [ciberduvidas, «Ter que» vs. «ter de»](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/ter-que-vs-ter-de/16291) e em [Dúvidas sobre o «ter de» e o «ter que»](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/duvidas-sobre-o-ter-de-e-o-ter-que/14247) .

Comment: A sua pesquisa foi muito boa, embora eu não tenha ficado muito esclarecido. Até estou com dificuldades em saber qual das duas formas eu uso e porquê. Acho que o que o AP queria dizer é que é mais usado "Tens **de** lavar os dentes agora!" como ordem. E "tens **que** experimentar sushi"  como probabilidade (probabilidade no sentido de ser provável e não obrigatório).

Comment: @JorgeB. obrigado Jorge, porém isso não será uma sugestão de uma possibilidade em vez de probabilidade propriamente dita? Vou incluir o seu exemplo de qualquer forma.

Comment: Sim, acho que era possibilidade que o AP queria dizer, ele que me corrija se eu estiver enganado. Foi assim que eu percebi quando li a pergunta. Até ia responder, mas não tenho factos sólidos para corroborar a minha teoria.

Comment: "Possibilidade" pode ser melhor sim, ou "sugestão". Os exemplos nos comentários aqui são bons e mostram a diferença que entendo entre as duas formas. Alguém sabe se isso tudo se aplica no Brasil só, ou em Portugal também? Estava pensando que pode ser uma influência de español de "tener que" e "hay que" para expressar obrigação.

Comment: @SandyMacPherson creio que o ["hay que" em Espanhol](http://www.studyspanish.com/lessons/tenque.htm) será mais aproximado a ["há que" em Português](http://www.lpeu.com.br/q/37pfg) que tem, de facto, algumas semelhanças às duas expressões que apresentou.

Comment: Da explicação entendo então que "Tenho **que** voltar para casa" é incorrecto? Deveria dizer sempre "Tenho **de** voltar para casa"?

Comment: @SérgioPereira ao dizer "tem **que** voltar", segundo as referências, está a transmitir uma informação sua, ou seja, no final pode decidir não voltar. Ao dizer "tem **de** voltar" está a mostrar que não tem outra escolha, ou seja, é obrigado a voltar.

Comment: Essa probabilidade é que não estou a ver. _ter que_ exprime sempre necessidade, obrigação, dever (não falando agora do "ter [] que", onde há qualquer coisa como _muito_, _pouco_, _nada_, etc. omitido). Noutras expressões que dão uma ideia mais mitigada de obrigação, como _haver de_, podemos falar de probabilidade: _Hás de fazer isto_ pode exprimir uma obrigação mais fraca, um vaticínio ou certeza por parte do falante. Mas não me parece que seja o caso com _ter de/que_.

Comment: Eu sempre ouvi usarem "tem que", e um dia alguém disse "mas na gramática de regência está escrito tem de", e estava. E como essas regras a gente aceita, passei a falar "tem de" pra tudo. Ao ouvir tem que ou tem de não me parece nada diferente ou que tenha significado diferente.

Comment: «Ele não vai sair, porque tem que estudar.» qual sentido de ter de dizer que a frase significa "Ele não vai sair, porque tem o que estudar" ao invés de usar esta última?

Answer (score 1):

Em ‘ter de’, a preposição *de* refere-se ao substantivo verbal que precede, no sentido de ‘ter necessidade *de* fazer algo’:

> *Tenho **de** comprar pão* : onde ‘comprar pão’ é objecto de uma necessidade

Já em ‘ter que’, o *que* é um pronome relativo que se refere ao que tem de ser feito. Existe aqui mais uma obrigatoriedade do que uma necessidade:

> *Tenho **que** comprar pão*:, isto é, tenho algo para fazer *que* é comprar pão.

**Referência**: *Dicionário de Erros e Problemas de Linguagem*, por Rodrigo de Sá Nogueira (citado em *Dicionário de Dúvidas, Dificuldades e Subtilezas da Língua Portuguesa*, por Edite Estrela e outros).

Comment: Vê o meu comentário da outra resposta, diz exatamente o contrário.

Comment: @JorgeB. Sim, a questão parece levantar bastantes dúvidas. A fonte que citei diz explicitamente que **de** é usado em situações de necessidade. No uso do **que** não refere obrigatoriedade, mas é a forma como eu interpreto. No seu exemplo: "Tens **que** experimentar sushi", eu entendo como um convite que é como uma 'obrigação educada', como se eu dissesse "Eu acho mesmo que **deves** experimentar sushi". Se eu disser "Tens **de** experimentar sushi", não sinto aqui tanta veemência, mas apenas uma sugestão.

Comment: É um assunto complicado. Mais na base do que parece do que o que será o correto

Answer (score 1):

Numa perspetiva de coerencia, o *que* em *ter que* significa algo, tal como nas seguintes frases:

- Tenho muito que fazer (= tenho muita coisa para fazer).
- Não tenho nada que comer (= não tenho nada para comer).

Como tal, temos também:

- Tenho que fazer… (= tenho algo para fazer)
- Tenho que comer… (= tenho algo para comer)

Por outro lado, a expressão com *de* no lugar de *que* expressa necessidade, obrigação, etc:

- Tenho de fazer… (= necessito de fazer)
- Tenho de comer… (= necessito de comer)

Agora, de um ponto de vista de uso, muitos falantes usam *tenho que* no sentido de *tenho de*.

Answer (score 0):

No Brasil pelo menos, as frases são perfeitamente sinônimas. Não é o caso das expressões "há de", que indica um futuro previsível (*Essa moda ridícula **há de** ser proibida* = Essa moda ridícula vai ser proibida) e "há que", que indica a necessidade de uma ação (*Essa moda ridícula **há que** ser proibida* = Essa moda ridícula precisa ser proibida). Talvez essa distinção leve alguns a acreditar que *Essa moda ridícula tem de acabar* é diferente de *Essa moda ridícula tem que acabar*, mas no uso cotidiano ambas são equivalentes, tanto no padrão (no qual talvez "tem que" seja marginalmente preferível) quanto no coloquial.

Comment: Note-se no entanto que "há que" é considerada uma expressão castelhana.
Repare-se na frase "não há que comer", que em português significa não há nada para comer.