# A frase "Você tem que se arriscar" está correta gramaticalmente?

Tags: gramática, português-brasileiro

A frase "Você tem que se arriscar" está correta gramaticalmente? O **se** ali é gramatical?

Vi essa [frase no SOpt](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/4670/5) e fiquei curioso.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Não deveria ser "Você tem que arriscar" ou "Você tem de arriscar", ou seja, sem o **se**?

Comment: Related: [Qual á diferença entre “ter que” e “ter de”?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/538/qual-%C3%A1-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-ter-que-e-ter-de)

Comment: P'los modos, a vinheta foi alterada e o "se" foi removido.

Comment: A regência do verbo Ter é de, mas no Brasil só se usa Tem que

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diria que tens razão. *Arriscar-se* tem a seguinte estrutura: *alguém [paciente] arrisca-se a qualquer coisa [tema, apenas oração reduzida/finita, não nome como mostra (3)]* e significa *correr o risco de*:

> (1) Arrisco-me a ter de fazer o trabalho todo.
>   (2) Arrisco-me a que tenha de fazer o trabalho todo.
>   (3) *Arrisco-me à necessidade de fazer o trabalho todo.

Ora parece-me que há uma confusão com um outro *arriscar*: *alguém [agente] arrisca qualquer coisa [nome ou oração reduzida]*. Só este *arriscar* pode significa *tentar, assumindo algum risco/perigo* ([sentido 2 do Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/arriscar)), que é o sentido que se quer transmitir (na minha interpretação). Por isso, reescrevê-la-ia desta forma:

> (4) Kevin, você às vezes tem de arriscar [].

A interpretação que faço do argumento vazio em cima é "ter comportamentos que possam ser mal recebidos", mas também admito que possa ser um argumento anulado, i.e., que se trata de uma afirmação genérica sobre *arriscar* (análogo a "quem não arrisca não petisca"). [adenda: reparei que o original é «Life is about taking risks»; neste caso é a interpretação genérica a mais próxima do original]

Para completar a resposta, *arriscar* (sem *se*) também pode significar *colocar em risco* ([sentido 1 do Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/arriscar)). Nesse caso, parece-me que o objeto direto tem de ser um nome, não pode ser uma oração.

Comment: Então é mesmo uma questão de interpretação, mas *Você tem que se arriscar* é gramatical? Se fosse *Você tem que se arriscar se for assaltar o banco* eu acharia gramatical, mas assim como está não.

Comment: @JorgeB. Acho que só pode ser gramatical se considerarmos que "arriscar" está a ser usado trasitivamente, com "se" a referir-se ao sujeito, como em _Como a cultura de regadio necessita de três a cinco vezes mais investimento que o sequeiro, «quantos agricultores terão capacidade para se arriscar na aventura? ", questiona Manuel Branco ._ (mas vê o meu último comentário na resposta do Centaurus; 1) acho que não era este o sentido pretendido: "tens de te pôr em risco" e 2) a frase tem uma ambiguidade desconfortvel).

Comment: A outra hipótese é termos um "arriscar-se" como descrevo no início da minha resposta, o que também não me parece ser o significado pretendido.

Answer (score 4):

As duas frases estão gramaticalmente corretas. Podemos usar tanto "tem que" quanto "tem de", sendo que os dois são de uso corrente em **ptBR**.  O que difere as duas frases, no meu entender, é que você pode **"arriscar alguma coisa"**, pode **"arriscar-se a sofrer alguma ação"** ou pode só **"arriscar-se".**

> - Para que fazer isso? Você não precisa se arriscar. (colocar-se em risco)
> - Você quer mesmo arriscar toda essa quantia? (dito em um casino)
> - Ela arriscou a própria vida.
> - Eu vou arriscar um palpite.
> - Ele arriscou cinco mil Euros na aposta.
> - Você se arrisca muito comigo. Exijo mais respeito.
> - Ela é viciada em bingo. Arrisca-se a perder tudo o que tem.
> - Não usas durex? Nunca?  Eu diria que tu te arriscas muito. (colocar-se em risco)

Comment: Eu coloquei ali o "de" por engano, a única diferença era o **se**. Fiz uma edição e mantive a com **de** para não invalidar a resposta, podes ver? Já agora usaste o *arriscar-se* em vez de *se arriscar* e acho que percebi. É que fica muito estranho "Você tem que se arriscar" em ptPT. Acho que soa melhor "Você tem que arriscar" no contexto que vi no SOpt.

Comment: *"o que difere **nas** duas frases", ou "o que difere entre as duas frases", ou "a diferença entre as duas frases", não?

Comment: Em Portugal, não estou a ver alguém a dizer "Tens mesmo de te arriscar?" (análoga à primeira), dir-se-ia "Tens mesmo de te pôr em risco?", talvez porque essa frase é ambígua entre "arriscar-se a qualquer coisa" (_se_ inerente, correr o risco, como na tua última frase) e "arriscar-se a si mesmo" (o significado geral de "arriscar" -- pôr em risco -- com _se_ a referir-se ao sujeito). "Você arrisca-se muito comigo" também nunca ouvi.

Comment: @Artefacto "você se arrisca muito comigo" é idiomático em ptBR e é quase uma ameaça.  Realmente temos muitas "diferenças transatlânticas" mas quando estou em Portugal nem as percebo muito quando o significado é compreendido.  Mesmo quando ouvi pela primeira vez "estás a ter idéia?"  entendi imediatamente o que significava.  Aqui no Brasil também temos grandes diferenças regionais.  O ptBR padrão é todo do meu conhecimento mas existem muitas expressões e vocábulos no extremo norte e no extremo sul que   fogem ao padrão.

Comment: "Estás-te a arriscar" (ou "estás a arriscar-te") usa-se em Portugal, mas está sempre qualquer coisa subentendida (estás-te a arriscar a levar um tabefe, por exemplo). Até sou capaz de admitir que esse "arriscar" é transitivo e não inacusativo (portanto significa "pores-te em risco" e não "correres o risco"). Mas em todo o caso nada disto é relevante para a pergunta, porque o significado desejado parece-me ser "tentar" como em "ele arriscou o remate à baliza"/"ele arriscou rematar à baliza". Nesse caso aquilo que se arrisca é dada ação, não a si mesmo, portanto não se poderia usar "se".

Comment: @JorgeB.  As duas formas são corretas (**casino e cassino**).  De qualquer modo obrigado.  Valeu a intenção.

Comment: @Centaurus peço desculpa é que em Portugal não existe cassino.

Comment: @JorgeB.  Existem vários.  Eu mesmo estive no Estoril. (risos)

Answer (score 2):

> - *Ter que* usa-se no sentido de [«ter algo para»](http://emportuguescorrecto.blogs.sapo.pt/39433.html).
> - *Ter de* serve para exprimir dever/obrigação/desejo/necessidade.
>
> Por exemplo ([ciberduvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/duvidas-sobre-o-ter-de-e-o-ter-que/14247)), se alguém quiser dizer que «tem muito trabalho», poderá utilizar a expressão «que fazer» para substituir a palavra «trabalho»: «Tenho muito que fazer.»

Alterando neste exemplo o *trabalho* por *risco*:

1. «você tem (muito) risco»;
2. substituindo risco pela expressão «que arriscar»:
3. «você tem (muito) que arriscar».

Ou seja, significa que existe um **risco quantificável** (algo que se tem/possui), e não significa uma necessidade de risco. Assim, neste sentido «você tem <s>se</s> risco» não tem lógica.

No entanto, mais recentemente ([ciberduvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/ter-que-vs-ter-de/16291)), *ter que* foi considerado como um **sinónimo** de *ter de*, logo:

1. «(você) tem de(que) arriscar» significa que existe uma necessidade ou um dever de arriscar;
2. colocando então o [pronome pessoal clítico](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/pronomes-cliticos-definicao/32576) *-se* ao lado do verbo ter:
3. «(você) [tem-se](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/hao-se-de/17416) de arriscar» é gramaticalmente correto, por isso:
4. «(você) tem de se arriscar» continuará correto (exemplo: [África tem de se industrializar](https://www.google.pt/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=29&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiojuHM-dvJAhWJqxoKHfYiDhQQFgjlATAc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.unido.org%2Ffileadmin%2Fuser_media_upgrade%2FWho_we_are%2FDG%2FJoint_Communique_Portuguese.pdf&usg=AFQjCNH9oJmiexIksZN2etwVfx9vlQxfyg&sig2=-f5kuuTkhdIW4uzwb-dXJg));
5. lembrando novamente que *ter que* neste caso é aceite como sinónimo de *ter de* então será também aceitável:
6. «(você) tem que se arriscar».

Comment: *tem-se de arriscar* é gramaticalmente correto? Sempre a aprender...

Comment: @JorgeB. Tal como [«hão-se de ...»](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/hao-se-de/17416) é gramaticalmente correto (século XVII). Esta expressão foi substituída mais recentemente por «tem-se de ...».

Comment: Armfoot não é "tem de se"?

Comment: @JorgeB. Os [pronomes clíticos](http://alfclul.clul.ul.pt/wochwel/documents/Cl%C3%ADticos_Gram%C3%A1tica%20do%20Portugu%C3%AAs_Gulbenkian.pdf) têm uma certa flexibilidade ou mobilidade nas frases (ver clíticos verbais p.2 e 7). Logo até pode dizer «você se tem de ...»