# Ter que vs ter de

Tags: significado, gramática

> Tenho que escrever uma carta a minha amiga Paola.
>
> Tenho de escrever uma carta a minha amiga Paola.

What is the difference between ter de and ter que? Some examples would be great.

Comment: Hi, this question was already asked before [here](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/538/qual-%C3%A1-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-ter-que-e-ter-de#answer-539).

Comment: @BrunoLopes Thanks for the translation-edit, happy new year!

Comment: You're welcome, happy new year for you too!  :)