# Há alguma diferença entre as construções "deve ser" e "há de ser"?

Tags: verbos, diferenças, significado-em-contexto

Recentemente estava estudando física e o livro didático dizia que, para se calcular a dioptria de uma lente, a distância focal (envolvida na fórmula) deveria estar fornecida em metros.

Mas acabei anotando no caderno do seguinte modo:

> A distância focal há de ser em metros.

Evidentemente, substituí (por vontade própria) o "dever" por "haver":

> A distância focal <del>deve</del> **há de** ser em metros.

Para mim, o sentido permanece o mesmo antes e depois da troca. Mas gostaria de saber se há alguma diferença, já que não tenho nenhum embasamento formal para isso.

Comment: Luiz, seria útil incluir a referência do livro e apresentar mais contexto. Assim, sem mais, eu consigo imaginar várias interpretações para *dever* (’obrigação’ versus ’probabilidade’) e ainda mais para *há de ser*.

Comment: Para mim, são clara e extremamente diferentes. Se a Maria me fala “hei de fazer macarronada”, creio que está dizendo que tem certeza (absoluta) ou que está muitíssimo motivada em fazer macarronada, como “hei matá-lo, hei de crucificá-lo, e hei de arrastar-te ao Inferno junto comigo, mesmo se um de nós estiver no Céu”. Se a Maria diz “devo fazer macarronada”, vejo que é sua intenção, sua idéia ou seu acreditar. Para mim “haver de” é uma afirmação extremamente forte. "Dever" indica que algo é provável, mas não necessariamente certo, enquanto "haver de" é extremissimamente mais forte.

Comment: Esta é a minha opinião, claro. Posso estar completamente errado.

Comment: Jacinto, eu editei a pergunta para tentar dar um pouco mais de contexto (espero ter melhorado um pouco rsrs). E Schilive, obrigado pela sua opinião. Eu também tenho a mesma sensação de que "haver" é _mais forte_, apesar do sentido de necessidade comum.

Comment: @LuizFelipe, eu acho que “haver de” indica futuro. “Deve” indica presente. “A distância focal há de ser de 4 metros” é no futuro (será de 4 metros), “a distância focal deve ser de quatro metros” é no presente (é de 4 metros).

Comment: O uso em Portugal é o mesmo que o @Schilive referiu. _Haver de_ não é nada apropriado nesse contexto. Talvez estejas a confundir com _haver que_ (como o _hay que_ em castelhano)?

Comment: @Artefacto, talvez seja por causa da semelhança de “haver” com “ter”. “Eu tenho um computador” = “eu hei um computador” e “tem três pessoas na festa” = “há três pessoas na festa”.

Comment: Luiz e @Artefacto, parece-me possível algo como, "será usada a fórmula tal-tal-tal, em que a distância há de ser indicada em metros", mas tem para mim um sabor arcaico. Num livro de física atual o que eu esperaria é mais como "fórmula tal-tal-tal, em que a distância é/está em metros"; *dever ser* por uma questão de grande delicadeza? Em fórmulas não há lugar para ambiguidades: tipicamente, trocas a unidade, e dá bronca. (Luiz, precisas de anteceder o nome de "@", como eu fiz para o Artefacto, para a pessoa receber notificação do comentário; exceto para o autor do post, que é sempre notificado)

Comment: @Jacinto acho que estou a ver onde queres chegar, que _haver de_ pode servir para ordens da mesma forma que o futuro simples ("Eſte tal ha de ſer do habito deſta Ordem..."). Mas parece-me uma construção mais apropriada para um edito do que para um livro didático.

Comment: @Artefacto, absolutamente. Mesmo de *dever*, não gosto muito.

Comment: há de ser é uma linguagem bastante formal.

Answer (score 1):

Minha resposta não pode ser autoritativa de jeito nenhum, mas eu me preguntei essas coisas como autodidato de português vivendo bastante no brasil.

Eu observo que formas com *haver* são muito mais raros (hoje em dia) que o povo popular não usa muito de forma ativa. A primeira construcção que eu aprendi com *haver* é "já há tanto tempo que eu não ouvi nada de você". Talvez "que houve?".

Mas "deve ser" e "tem que ser" são as formas mais comum que eu ouço, e "tem de ser" ou "há de ser" é muito raro que eu ouço isso em vernacular.

Então, para a exploração completo do campo dessas construções você tem que (!) incluir *ter de* e *ter que*.

- há de ser
- tem que ser
- tem de ser [Qual a diferença entre "ter que" e "ter de"?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/538/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-ter-que-e-ter-de)
- deve ser

Eu creio que não há explicação definitiva sobre a diferença de significado entre essas formas, e que talvez tem apenas algumas conotações que algumas pessoas sentem, mas depende muito de qual região, qual época, e qual classe social vem a pessoa.

Em muitas línguas europeias existe esse polimorfismo dessas expressões com auxiliar. Em inglês, por exemplo:

- there has to be (cognato de "ter que ser" ou "há de ser"
- there should be (analogo a "deve ser")

ou em alemão a mesma coisa:

- es hat zu sein
- es sollte sein

a diferença entre essas construcções não são fixos embora pode haver connotações suteis sendo sentido diferente por pessoas de origem e épocas diferentes.

Comment: Lamento os votos negativos, especialmente sem comentários.

Answer (score 1):

[Neste link](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/valor-modal-do-auxiliar-haver-de/34880) discute-se um pouco os valores modais do verbo haver, mas, para todos os efeitos, deixo mais alguns exemplos para discussão:

1. *Hei de fazer um bolo seguindo a receita deste livro. / Devo fazer um bolo seguindo a receita deste livro.*

Em ambos os casos, estou a falar de um **plano** para o futuro, mas existem ligeiras diferenças. Quando digo que ***"hei de"*** fazer um bolo, isto expressa **uma intenção,** que posso ou não cumprir, eventualmente, no futuro. Mas se digo que ***"devo"*** fazer um bolo, então estou a indicar **uma tarefa** - é necessário que eu faça um bolo (usando a receita daquele livro em particular).

2. *Hás de limpar o teu quarto. / Deves limpar o teu quarto.*

Aqui, em ambos os casos, estamos a indicar uma
**responsabilidade/tarefa**. Porém,  no segundo caso transmite-se uma sensação de **obrigação** maior - facilmente podia substituir o verbo *"dever"* por *"ter de"* sem perda de significado.

3. *A encomenda há de chegar amanhã. / A encomenda deve chegar amanhã.*

Neste caso, ambos os verbos são usados para expressar
**possibilidade**. Mas é de notar que, para além da primeira frase ser mais **informal** (caso estivesse a falar com um cliente sobre a sua encomenda, seria mais correto utilizar *"dever de"*), no segundo, transmite-se que **existe alguma probabilidade forte** de a encomenda, de facto, chegar amanhã e não noutro dia qualquer.

Em suma, ainda que ambos os verbos estejam corretos e podem ser usados, a diferença está no contexto e adequação em cada caso. Para expressar algo que é, precisamente, um **dever/obrigação, uma necessidade, ou algo que tem uma boa probabilidade de acontecer**, é mais frequente utilizar-se o verbo *"dever"*. Ao passo que ***"haver de"*** é mais frequentemente utilizado para **possibilidades, planos para o futuro, expectativas** - que podem ou não acontecer, sem grande certeza - e ainda que também possa ser utilizada como obrigação ([ver link](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/valor-modal-do-auxiliar-haver-de/34880)), isto é menos frequente.

Assim, no exemplo concreto que apresentaste, seria mais adequado usar "dever", dado que estás a falar de uma obrigação/necessidade, para que a fórmula te dê os resultados corretos, e não apenas do que planeias usar ou encontrar.

Relativamente ao uso de *"dever de"* (discutido noutras respostas), deixo a citação abaixo:

> "O Novo Dicionário Aurélio da Língua Portuguesa (1997) ensina que *dever*, seguido da preposição *de* e de um *verbo no infinitivo*, indica probabilidade, suposição: (…) "*Deve de* chover hoje". Mas acrescenta: "O uso moderno da língua pouco atende a essa peculiaridade; assim, é mais comum que se diga, com a mesma aceção, *deve chover hoje*". Em Portugal, a ausência do *de* também é mais corrente, e até sentida como mais correta." - *in* [Ciberdúvidas da Língua Portuguesa](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/dever-de/4260)

Espero que isto tenha ajudado.

Answer (score -1):

posso estar errado, mas, "deve ser" expressa uma afirmaçao seguido por duvida, enquanto "há de ser" expressa uma afirmaçao do que acontecerar no futuro.